# How to create a ftp server using cmd in my windows computer

Tags: ftp

Can somebody tell me how to create an ftp server using only cmd and also how to configure it using only cmd

Answer (score 0):

The command prompt ftp in windows is a client ftp. You can't use it like a ftp server. You need an ftp server software. You can probably find one for free online.